# Specify Converter inside DataTemplate in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a user control that has a Label and a ComboBox. It is used like this:

```xaml
<cc:LabeledComboBox
    HeaderLabelContent="Months"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllMonths}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMonth}"/>
```

And here is what the UserControl XAML looks like:

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="CustomControls.LabeledComboBox" ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:MonthEnumToTextConverter x:Key="MonthEnumToTextConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label x:Name="LblValue" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="LstItems">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- TODO: Fix so that the Converter can be set from outside -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MonthEnumToTextConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In the comment above you can see my problem. The control is generic (the ComboBox can contain pretty much anything) but on the Binding inside the DataTemplate I have specified a Converter that is very specific.

**How can I specify the Converter from outside the UserControl?**

I'm hoping for some kind of solution using a dependency property like this:

```xaml
<cc:LabeledComboBox
    ...
    ItemConverter="{StaticResource MonthEnumToTextConverter}"/>
```

Comment: You may use an internal converter (declared as static resource simliar to the MonthEnumToTextConverter in your example) that delegates its Convert calls to another converter which is settable as dependency property.

Comment: @Clemens I missed your comment. This sounds like an excellent idea! Present an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an internal binding converter that delegates its Convert and ConvertBack calls to one set is settable as dependency property:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:InternalItemConverter x:Key="InternalItemConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        ...
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding
                        Converter={StaticResource InternalItemConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The internal converter could look like this:

```
class InternalItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public LabeledComboBox LabeledComboBox { get; set; }

    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (LabeledComboBox != null && LabeledComboBox.ItemConverter != null)
        {
            value = LabeledComboBox.ItemConverter.Convert(
                value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (LabeledComboBox != null && LabeledComboBox.ItemConverter != null)
        {
            value = LabeledComboBox.ItemConverter.ConvertBack(
                value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

And finally the dependency property code like this:

```
public partial class LabeledComboBox : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemConverterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemConverter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(LabeledComboBox));

    public IValueConverter ItemConverter
    {
        get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(ItemConverterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemConverterProperty, value); }
    }

    public LabeledComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var converter = (InternalItemConverter)Resources["InternalItemConverter"];
        converter.LabeledComboBox = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple datatemplates for the the combobox items and then you can control what and how you want to display your comboxitem like below

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MonthDataTypeViewModel}" >
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MonthEnumToTextConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type vm:OtherViewModel}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you do not have multiple viewmodels then you can use a template selector to select different data templates based on some property in your viewmodel.

Comment: This could work, although it feels like a work-around. Unless I find some other solution, I guess this is what I'll have to do.

Comment: I agree it looks like a work around (one of the issues I found when I started working with wpf) But I think a template selector would do a perfect job you, especially if you can make it really generic and use it for other purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: reworked to not use my personal example to avoid confusion ...

On your user control code behind you could define your dependency property.

I don't know what type your converters derive from so change 'myConverterType' to the type of converters you use.

```
public bool ItemConverter
{
    get { return (myConverterType)GetValue(IntemConverterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemConverterProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemConverterProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemConverter", typeof(myConverterType), 
    typeof(LabeledComboBox), null);
```

In XAML you should then just be able to set the converter property as per your example. In my example it is used like this:

```
<cc:LabeledComboBox ItemConverter="{StaticResource theSpecificConverter}"/>
```

Then use this property, on your user control xaml, like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="LstItems">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={Binding ItemConverter, ElementName=UserControl}}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: My problem is not the `ShowNumericControl` from your example, but the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

Comment: My example was about how to define and use a dependency property - the example is obviously not exactly what you need, but I thought it would give you the pointers you need.

You need to create a dependency property called 'Converter', or something like that, but I didn't want to give you exact code because I don't know what type your converter is (which is needed when defining the dependency property). My last bit of code is just showing how I use *my* dependency property (a boolean called ShowNumericControl) but I guess it then using a converter confused the issue. Apologies.

Comment: What type is your converter? Is there a type that all your possible converters will use?

Comment: My converter in an IValueConverter.

Comment: In the current state the code in your answer doesn't work. You can only have Bindings on dependency properties, and Converter is not a dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. Presenting the solution that I'll use until I find something better.

I don't specify only the Converter, but the whole DataTemplate:

```
<cc:LabeledComboBox>
    <cc:LabeledComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MonthEnumToTextConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </cc:LabeledComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</cc:LabeledComboBox>
```

And here's the ItemTemplate dependency property:

```
public partial class LabeledComboBox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemTemplate",
        typeof(DataTemplate),
        typeof(LabeledComboBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate), ItemTemplateChanged));

    private static void ItemTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var labeledComboBox = (LabeledComboBox)d;
        labeledComboBox.LstItems.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)e.NewValue;
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    // ...
}
```